# Difference between a || a = b and a = a || b in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone put light on this expression. Seems like both are same but they are not.

```
a || a = b or a ||= b
```

and

```
a = a || b
```

if

`a = 4` and `b = 6`, output is always `4`

This always confuse and misconcept me. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: Might want to read [this article](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html). `a || a = b`, `a = a || b`, and `a ||= b` are all slightly different in nature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a || a = b
```

looks for `a` if `a` is truthy, returns `a`, otherwise `a = b` is done i.e. you assign `b`'s value to `a`.

```
a = a || b
```

This is an assignment operation. Here you are assigning value to `a` irrespective of what value it holds. So `a` equals `a || b`. In second part of the statement you are looking for `a`. If its value is truthy you are assigning it back to `a` itself, else you are assigning `b`'s value to `a`.

**TL;DR**

`a = a || b` is assigning a value *(depending on condition)* to `a` irrespective of what value it holds.

`a ||= b` return `a` if already present, else does `a = b`

**Explaining with example:**

You can think of `a || a = b` as `a || (a = b)`. Now lets assume `a = 4` and `b = 6`.

Since by order of precedence, this is an OR operation and since order of operations for OR is left to right we start with first `a`:

```
 # lets call this Fig. 1
      a || (a = b)
      ^
      |
      .
   (here)
```

This `a` has value 4, which is a truthy value. Therefore the evaluation stops then and there and `4` is returned. ( *Why? Hint:*  `true || anything = true`)

Now lets assume `a = nil` and `b = 6`. We start again from same place (Fig. 1). Since `a` is `nil` which is falsely in Ruby, we move to the right side of the OR operation, i.e. `a = b`

```
 # lets call this Fig. 2
      a || (a = b)
              ^
              |
              .
           (here)
```

As this is an assignment operation, it will get executed and we will end up assigning `6` to `a`.

Coming back to `a = a || b`. You can think this as `a = (a || b)`. Clearly by order of precedence its an assignment operation. Since order of operations for assignment is right to left, `(a || b)` is evaluated first.

```
 # lets call this Fig. 3
      a = (a || b)
             ^
             |
             .
          (here)
```

If `a = 4` and `b = 6`, `a || b` will return `4` *(as discussed above)*. Else if `a = nil` and `b = 6`, `a || b` will return `6`.

Now whatever value is returned from this `||` operation is getting assigned to the first `a`.

```
 # lets call this Fig. 4
      a = (a || b)
      ^
      |
      .
    (here)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain with example which might help us to understand it better.

Comment: @ChitrankSamaiya I have tried to explain my answer with examples in my latest edit. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

A common **misconception** is that :

`a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`, but it behaves like `a || a = b`

In `a = a || b`, a is set to something by the statement on every run, whereas with `a || a = b`, a is only set if a is logically false (i.e. if it's nil or false) because **||** is 'short circuiting'.

Let me keep that **simple** :

> That is, if the left hand side of the || comparison is true, there's
>   no need to check the right hand side.

more reference [RubyInside](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html)